# how to set up size image fitting with box size in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla

i want to fit my image size with the size of box slider in my joomla..
because the image appears with the original size that makes your slider gotten big with the image size.
where i can change my code for the slider box image ?
 here is the code

```
ul.carousel-inner{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;}
.carousel-inner > .item {
/* -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s; */
}
.carousel-inner > .active {

        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item {
        /* -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out 0s; */
    }

    .carousel-inner > .active {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .item{
        -webkit-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .prev,
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .active.left {
    left: 0;
    top: -100%;
}
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    top: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-caption h4{

}
.carousel-control.control-box{
    padding: 8px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
[class*="control-group-"],
[class*="control-group-"] .carousel-control{
    position: relative;
}
[class*="control-group-"] .carousel-control{
    margin: 0;
}
.control-group-xs{
    width: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.carousel-vertical .control-group-xs{
    width: 10px;
    margin: -10px 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.carousel-vertical .carousel{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.carousel-vertical .carousel-inner{

}
.control-group-xs .carousel-control.control-box {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    line-height: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: block;
}
.control-group-xs .carousel-control.control-box > .glyphicon,
.control-group-xs .carousel-control.control-box > .fa {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    line-height: 8px;
}
.carousel-control.control-box.control-top{
    top: auto;
    bottom: 100%;
}
.carousel-control.control-box.control-bottom{
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-control.control-box.control-middle{
    /* top: auto;
    bottom: 50%; */
}
.carousel-control.control-box [class*="glyphicon-"],
.carousel-control.control-box [class*="icon-"]{
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.carousel-control.control-sm{
    margin-bottom: -17px;
}
.carousel-control.control-sm,
.carousel-control.control-sm [class*="glyphicon-"],
.carousel-control.control-sm [class*="icon-"] {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.carousel-control.control-lg{
    margin-bottom: -23px;
}
.carousel-control.control-lg,
.carousel-control.control-lg [class*="glyphicon-"],
.carousel-control.control-lg [class*="icon-"] {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.carousel-control-group{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.carousel-control-group.top{
    /* bottom: auto;
    top: 0; */
    bottom: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.carousel-control-group.left{
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
.carousel-control-group .carousel-control{
    position: relative;
    margin: 1px;
}

.carousel-inner > .item{
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner > .item .oeffect{
    position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.active .oactive{

}
.carousel{
    /* z-index: 0; */
}
.ot_slidenav.carousel-indicators{
    display: inline-block;
    left: auto;
    right: 15px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
}
.ot_slidenav.carousel-indicators li{
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.ot-indicators{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.ot-indicators .carousel-indicators{
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.ot_indicators .carousel-indicators{
    top: -30px;
    right: 0px;
}
.carousel-indicators li{
    /* margin: 4px; */
}
.carousel-indicators li.ot-square {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li:hover,
.carousel-indicators li.active{

}
.ot-slidenav{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
.ot-slidenav .carousel-control{
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.90;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.ot-slidenav .carousel-control:hover,
.ot-slidenav .carousel-control:focus{
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: can you put up a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle? or print screen? sorry im newbie :D

Comment: fiddle would be more useful

Comment: oh,, thank you, but still confused for using it